# String Compression

Tags: javascript, algorithm

A list of strings should be compressed into their shortest forms by expressing repetitions with numbers. If a letter only shows up only once, the `"1"` before it should be omitted.

For example

`"aabbaccc"` can be compressed into `"2a2ba3c"` if subdivided into units of 1.

`"ababcdcdababcdcd"` can be compressed into `"2ab2cd2ab2cd"` if subdivided into units of 2.

`"abcabcdede"` can be compressed into `"2abcdede"` if subdivided into units of 3 and so on.

I need to compress the following strings to the following shortest lengths

1. `"aabbaccc"`, 7
2. `"ababcdcdababcdcd"`, 9
3. `"abcabcdede"`, 8
4. `"abcabcabcabcdededededede"`, 14
5. `"xababcdcdababcdcd"`, 17

My code only works for case 1 and 5 because I only know how to subdivide strings into units of 1. I am not sure how to subdivide for units greater than 1 and need someone to edit my code.

```
// traverse string, keep count of repeated chars
// if cur and next char is the same, inc count
// otherwise, concat cur char and count to output string, reset counter to 1
// return compressed string, only if the length is less than the original string, otherwise, return original string

let stringCompression = (s) => {
  let out = '';
  let count = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    let cur = s[i];
    let next = s[i + 1];

    if (cur === next) {
      count++;
    } else {
      out += String(count) + cur;
      final = out.replace('1','')
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  return final.length < s.length ? final : s;
}
console.log(stringCompression('aabbaccc').length); // is 7
```

For anyone who can read Korean, the original source is question 1 from [here](https://tech.kakao.com/2019/10/02/kakao-blind-recruitment-2020-round1/)

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, your output makes no sense.

Consider `ababa`

There's no way of knowing from the output that `2aba` is supposed to represent `ababa`  (*2x `ab` + `a`*) and not `abaaba` (*2x `aba`*) completely different strings, yet according to your proposed algorithm both validly compressed

Comment: what about numbers in the original string? gzip example using CompressionStream https://playcode.io/632125/ 100k bytes to 130 bytes.

Comment: `2aba` would be `abaaba` subdivided into units of 3. `2aba` would be `ababa` subdivided into units of 2. I don't think it's the original that matters, but the final shortest result. This is taken from a past job interview question. I'm just trying to reverse engineer the solution (which the company never posted)

Comment: Side question: Is this known as run length encoding?

Comment: I don't know enough about algorithms to identify if it is run length encoding sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call compression parts a chunk. For example, in "ababcdcdababcdcd" (which can be compressed either to "2ab2cd2ab2cd" or to "2ababcdcd") "ab", "cd" and "abcd" are chunks.
You can write a cycle:

```
for(let i = N; i > ; i--)
```

where `N` is the maximum possible length of a chunk (obviously it is the length of a string divided by 2) and `i` is current chunk size we assume. So we will start looking for the biggest possible chunks. In case of "xababcdcdababcdcd" it is:

1. "xababcdc"
2. "ababcdcd"
3. ...
   And each time you find a repeating chunk, you replace it

However, there is another path. I think it may be possible to solve this task by using Recursive Regular Expressions.